# How to debug the flow initiated on record insert/update?

Tags: visual-workflow, flow-builder

I know there are several questions on how to debug the flow, but this is based on the recent update flow has received.

I am using record insert-update type of flow and making use of $Record, now I want to debug the flow, but because it is not an input variable, while debugging the flow it doesn't ask for the value on which the flow should run.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to test it on a record simulating the use case in a Sandbox. You may get an error-message/e-mail. In addition, you can capture some of the error information and have the flow send you an e-mail (I have not tried this, but there are posts and a Salesforce Labs solution on this.

Comment: Could you please post those links, it will help everyone?

Comment: Sure. You don't have to use a Labs solution, but there is one mentioned here: https://medium.com/inside-the-salesforce-ecosystem/salesforce-employee-built-4-appexchange-apps-c6feba7c6630 . Here is a direct link: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FMhi0UAD . And I know https://jenwlee.com/ flow examples include a mail the error step sometimes.